# RealmSwift returning wrong value for Int

Tags: ios, database, realm

I've been implementing RealmSwift into my application and I have an "Event" class which has `dynamic var lastActionId: Int = 0` and when I finish downloading a response from the server, I update this value (and it works, as you can see in the browser below).

However, when I try to access that integer when I make my next request, it is ALWAYS 0 and is refusing to return any other value. The object is correct, as I have also queried the name, startDate, endDate, etc which are all returned as they are in the browser. However, the Int isn't and always returns 0.

Why could this be?

[image: RealmSwift]

Comment: what happens if you remove the explicit `= 0` assignment?

Comment: I get "class Event has no initializers" and Xcode prompts me to add the explicit assignment. I could use the RealmOptional<Int> if it worked but for some strange reason, the value doesn't even appear in the browser when I use that.

Comment: Can you expand on the self.eventId used for the key in `objectForPrimaryKey()`? The code for your `Event: Object` would also be helpful.

Comment: Were you able to work this out in the end? If not, can you please provide a little more information on the `Event` object?

Comment: Check if the value is marked as `dynamic`!